# I get an error `` (node: 2813) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined '' at node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

(node:2813) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You will have this exception if your application throws an exception:

- Inside the promise executor function without catch function
- Inside catch function

---

```
promise.then(() => {throw new Error("message")});
promise.then(() => {doSomething()}).catch(() => {throw new Error("message")});
```